# Overload resolution of constrained functions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overloading, c++20, c++-concepts

Is the call to `f` ambiguous? Since one of the functions is more constrained than
the other, I wouldn't expect there to be any ambiguity. Yet, `GCC 12.2` and `Clang trunk` reject the
code, in contrast to `Clang 15`, `MSVC 19.33`, and `MSVC trunk`.

[Code example](https://godbolt.org/z/aM6zdoh3c):

```
template<typename...>
int f();

template<typename = void>
int f() requires true;

static_assert(sizeof(f()));
```

The error produced by GCC:

```
<source>:7:23: error: call of overloaded 'f()' is ambiguous
    7 | static_assert(sizeof(f()));
      |                      ~^~
<source>:2:5: note: candidate: 'int f() [with <template-parameter-1-1> = {}]'
    2 | int f();
      |     ^
<source>:5:5: note: candidate: 'int f() requires  true [with <template-parameter-1-1> = void]'
    5 | int f() requires true;
      |     ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether viable overloads from function templates are more constrained is considered only if the function templates are otherwise equivalent (except for potentially the return type). It is not sufficient that the call would otherwise be ambiguous.

In particular the corresponding template parameters must be *equivalent*, see [[temp.func.order]/6.2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.func.order#6.2.2). A template parameter that is a parameter pack (as in the first overload) is not *equivalent* to one that isn't (as in the second overload), see [[temp.over.link]/6.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.over.link#6.2).

So the constraint doesn't matter for deciding which candidate is better. The call is ambiguous.

Comment: I tried to fiddle around with defaulted template arguments but I guess the transformed template will simply run into the length requirement of the parameter lists stated in [`[temp.func.order]/6.1`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.func.order#6.1). So it seems that both `Clang 10-15` and `MSVC 19` should not accept the code. Having `Clang trunk` reject it also seems to underline this position.